# hide rows from datatables using server side processing in laravel 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I'm trying to hide rows from datatabel using sever side processing .

So I'm using the following code :

my view :

```
  <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mb-4 data-table-rows data-tables-hide-filter">
                        <table id="datatableRows" class="data-table responsive nowrap"
                            data-order="[[ 1, &quot;desc&quot; ]]">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Image</th>
                                    <th>Nom</th>
                                    <th>CIN</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                   <th>Action</th> 
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                       

                        </table>
                        

                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want to hide rows with value of column `actif = 0`

so I have the following script :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      
    
    $('#hide').click(function(){
    alert("in");
     
     //  $('#datatableRows').DataTable().destroy();
      var table = $('#datatableRows').DataTable({
    
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax:{
             url: "{{ route('castingss.filter_status') }}",
            },
            columns:[
            
             {
              data: 'photo',
              name: 'photo',
              render: function(data, type, full, meta){
    
                        return "<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + data +  " class='list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left' />";
              },
              orderable: false
             },
             {data:'nom',
              name: 'nom',
              render:function(data,type,full,meta){
                return "<a href='profile'>" + data + "</a>";
              }
             },
              {
              data: 'cine',
              name: 'cine'
             },
             {
             data:   "tel1",
             name:   "tel1"
             },
            
             
             {
              data: 'action',
              name: 'action',
              orderable: false
             }
            ] 
           });
      
    
     });
    
    </script>
```

And My Controller :

```
function filter_status(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        if($request->actif =0)
      {
       $data = DB::table('castings')
         ->where('actif', array($request->actif = 1))
         ->get();
      }
       return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
    }
    return view('Casting.castingss');
}
```

When I execute my code I get the following alert :

```
DataTables warning: table id=datatableRows - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
```

I don't know what s exactly the problem

Thank you in advance

Comment: some how the data table is already initiated before. check out where it's getting initialized first.

Comment: I solve it , but nothing happens , the rows doesn't hided